# C array is overwriting an index

Tags: c, arrays

I am reading from 2 different files and running this function on each. 
The file format is

```
2
3  
8 7 6 
5 4 3
```

The code I am using is

```
void readFile(char txtName[], int k, int matrix){
    int c = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int x = 0;
    //Open file
    FILE *txt;
    txt = fopen(txtName, "r");
    //Go till the end of the file
    while( fscanf(txt, "%d", &c) != EOF ){
        //For assigning matrix A
        if(matrix == 1){
            //Used to skip over the first 2 inputs.
            if(x > 1){
                //Got to the end of the row increase to the next row.
                if(j == k){
                    i++;
                    j = 0;
                }
                //Assiging c to A
                A[i][j] = c;
                printf("%d A in matrix %d %d\n", A[i][j], i, j);
                j++;
            }
        x++;
        }            
    }
    fclose(txt);
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )  {
    readFile(argv[1], k, 1);
    int m = 2;
    int k = 3;
    int i;
    int j;
    for(i=0; i < m; i++){
        for(j=0; j < k; j++){
            printf("%d", A[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

I am trying to initialize an 2 dimensional array with the file so that it is a matrix. The first value of the file is the m and the second is the k. So from the file posted. it is a 2x3 matrix with the values below it. A is a global array set to A[2][3];

The issue I am having is when I run this code my array comes out with

```
8 7 5
5 4 3
```

and I have no clue why. I have put a lot of print statements for debugging. When it comes to i = 0 and j = 2 it prints out 6. But when I print the array after the function A[0][2] = 5. Where is the error that I am making?

Comment: It is very hard to follow what is going on here; you're also missing the definition of `A` and `B`. However this could occur if you've defined `A[2][3]` and using it as if `A[3][2]`...

Comment: Also, why are you using an `if` choosing between the matrix?! Instead pass either `A` or `B` into the function as an argument.

Comment: It would be better to use a pair of nested loops for the 2 dimensions, and test the `fscanf` return value for `1`, if not that is a fault.

Comment: please work out a proper [mcve]. If the fault occurs with the code that reads in A, there is no need to have *any* code that reads in `B`. Also please add a `main` function that demonstrates this and how are you printing it.

Comment: The A and B are defined on the global, and I don't pass them to the function because I didn't know how I would depict between which is A and Which is B.

Comment: @Shawnzye Just pass the array `A` or `B` as an argument to the function.

Comment: You can have a parameter like `int matrix[][3]`

Comment: and you can use `A` or `B` as an argument

Comment: But if both matrixes are 3x3 Then how I depict which is which?

Comment: What is `k` in calling `readFile(argv[1], k, 1);`?

Comment: wrong `k` cause your undesired output

Answer (score 0):

Your problem probably with `while( fscanf(txt, "%d", &c) != EOF )`. Just try with `while( fscanf(txt, "%d", &c))` and check.